# php microtime() format value

Tags: php, optimization, microtime

PHP's microtime() returns something like this:

```
0.56876200 1385731177 //that's msec sec
```

That value I need it in this format:

```
1385731177056876200 //this is sec msec without space and dot
```

Currently I'm doing something this:

```
$microtime =  microtime();
$microtime_array = explode(" ", $microtime);
$value = $microtime_array[1] . str_replace(".", "", $microtime_array[0]);
```

Is there a one line code to achieve this?

Comment: `echo str_replace('.', '', microtime(true));`

Comment: @N.B. unsing microtime(true) gives me less characters, the standar string return is more suitable for my needs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the entire thing in one line using regex:

```
$value = preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', microtime());
```

**Example**:

```
<?php
    $microtime = microtime();
    var_dump( $microtime );
    var_dump( preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', $microtime) );
?>
```

**Output**:

```
string(21) "0.49323800 1385734417"  
string(19) "1385734417049323800"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/BSqp0LYv)

Comment: `$value = preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', microtime(true));` will not work as expected. And why using a regular expression where a simple calculation is enough?

Comment: @l-x It **does** work as expected though - check the demo. OP wanted it in a single line - you can't do that without regex. "*Is there a one line code to achieve this?*".

Comment: @l-x It will without `true`. Plus your answer isn't in the format that OP wanted.

Comment: @h2ooooooo that's what I'm talking about! =) thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, due to PHP's restriction for float presentation (till 14 digits for whole numeric), there's little sense in using `microtime()` with `true` as parameter.

So, you'll have to work with it as with string (via `preg_replace()`, for example) or adjust [`precision`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) to use native function call:

```
var_dump(1234567.123456789);//float(1234567.1234568)
ini_set('precision', 16);
var_dump(1234567.123456789);//float(1234567.123456789)
```

-so, it will be like:

```
ini_set('precision', 20);
var_dump(str_replace('.', '', microtime(1)));//string(20) "13856484375004820824"
```

-still not "one-liner", but you're aware of reason that causes such behavior so you can adjust `precision` only once and then use that.